# C# Building a website Form response using WebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

I have a device with a built-in WebGUI that is accessible through it's IP address. I am trying to be able to programmatically manipulate inputs to the device with a console app. The device's login page (`https://192.168.x.x/login.html`) contains the following form:

```
<form class="settingNameTxt" method="post" action="back.shtml">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" size="8" maxlength="8" name="Password"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="reset"/>
/form>
```

I want to build a WebRequest that is the equivalent of a user viewing the page in a browser, filling in the password field, and clicking the `Submit` button. I've searched around here and found a few things that seem to give me the idea that it can be done, but I'm struggling to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: What Framework are you targeting in your project? What kind of App you created? WPF or WinForms?

Comment: .NET4.0 and it is a console app.

Comment: You need not to walk through html only if you wat to login. Just send `WebRequest` POST HTTP with miltipart/form-data in it like browser does, and you'll receive the cookie for the next requests. As a first step.

Comment: Allow me to clarify - I know I don't need to walk through the html. Building and sending the ```WebRequest``` with the form data in it is the part I don't know how to do.